# Scrolling to a item in menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have a menu which consists of a `<ul>` containing `<li>` elements. When opened the menu should be scrolled to the current active `<li>` element which is marked by the respecting class `<li active>`.

The menu will currently be wrapped into its div. When the user then hovers the mouse into a certain region the menu will pop up and will jump to the current active li element.

```
var ScrollToCurrentPageInMenu = function(menu) {
    var posObject = $("#subnavigation").parent().find("li.active")[0].offsetTop;
    console.log("posObject: " + posObject);
    $("#subnavigation").parent().scrollTo(posObject);
};
```

Currently `$("#subnavigation").parent().find("li.active")[0].offsetTop;` is wrong. When I execute the jump with the manually opened menu and query over Firebug or Firefox it works.

I tried to use offset().top or position().top but it seemed to require a bit more logic then the current approach. ScrollTo alone works when the current `<li>` element is not expanded and scrollTop scrolls to far up.

I know it is a bit fuzzy but I can't publish the project.

So my questions:

- Is there a better method then .offsetTop?
- Is there a design mistake (using .offsetTop)?
- Why does Firebug or the Webconsole deliver unequal values?

Answer (score 0):

The first (rough) approach I can think is:

If the `<li>` has a fixed height, I would get the index of the `.active` one and the set the `top` property to something like `li_height * li_index * -1`

Then animate the changing of `top` property to the computed value

I'm sure there's a better solution